# Joomla invisible menu item showing on the screen

Tags: php, joomla, menu, duplicates, menuitem

Someone with admin rights have deleted an article from the menu, and I can't find it, the problem is, that article is duplicated on the main page and I can't find it to permanently delete it, not even in the menu trash.

When I enter in the menu manager it tells me that I have 6 itens in it, but actually I only have 4 itens, and these 2 are showing on the page, have a look at [arel.com.br](http://arel.com.br) on the footer right side you will see 2 itens: "26º Torneio Dupla Centenária & 10ª Copa Diamante".

I want to delete those itens but I can't find them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely as simple as clearing the cache on your Joomla website (not the browser cache). If this doesn't work, then the module is grabbing its data from another menu, you'll need to find out which.